# cocos2d-x 3.0 rc1, create project on Windows

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've downloaded Cocos2d-x 3.0 rc1 on my Windows machine. I'm trying to figure out how to build and create a new game project. On older versions there was a script. How is it done on Windows with the new version?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, here is how I solved it:

```
cd cocos2d-x
./setup.py
```

Close and open the terminal again then:

```
cocos new MyGame -p com.your_company.mygame -l cpp -d A_FILE_PATH_FOR_YOUR_PROJECT
```

Comment: Did you have to have Android NDK installed on your machine?  I would like to get it to work on Windows Desktop first

Comment: Did U run the python script on a Windows machine using the Python terminal?

Comment: The ./setup.py script seems to add an environment variable to my Windows system. COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT=C:\Users\bbcc\blocks_clean\externals\cocos2d-x\tools/cocos2d-console/bin      . The problem I see is that the cocos2d-console folder seems to be empty. Do I need to build something before running the script ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were on windows. But as far as I know you don't need to run an extra script. Setup.py is the enough. Check the github rep for more info -> https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x